# What does the Mirror Pool actually duplicate?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

In My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic Season 3, Episode 3: Too Many Pinkie Pies, Pinkie Pie uses the Mirror Pool to make clones of herself so that she can have fun in multiple places simultaneously. The first scene where she does this can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8wZ3ANVeTU).

However, the clones seem quite far from precise. Sure, they *look* like Pinkie, but they seem to have much less restraint over themselves, and only appear to share some of her memories.

Then, if the Mirror Pool doesn't duplicate ponies perfectly, what parts of them *does* it duplicate? Which aspects of their personality, and which parts of their memory would it put into the clones?

Comment: Don't you think you're taking that *a bit too serious*? Remember that, inspite all the fandom, it's still a children's show where things, especially those related to Pinkie Pie, aren't always supposed to be perfectly logical.

Comment: @Dominik Maybe, but I judged the appropriateness of this question based on other MLP questions that have done well here. I'm not looking for some canon answer, but more of a deductive answer (as many of those questions have). I think that's reasonable to ask for, especially given that other MLP questions have done so as well.

Comment: Scifi.SE is a Very Serious site. Not like we have questions about aliens who don't actually exist or silly things about Wizard Schools here.

Comment: to be fair, one episode in season 7 implies the pond can duplicate **rocks** too, since it apparently duped Maud's pet rock Boulder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My impression is that the pool duplicated only what was foremost in Pinkie's mind when the clones were created--whatever was her purpose in creating the clones. In our case, that was clearly "I want to have fun!". There were certainly some thoughts about her friends in there, but since they weren't directly her focus, the clones got only murky information about them.

Comment: In a word, [fun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGU1S1qyhTk).

Answer (score 0):

So as I see it the pinkie clones always are saying fun fun fun. That would mean that the clones only got the fun pinkie instead of a full flown pinkie. I think that pinkie was exited about being cloned that that part was cloned. If pinkie was being serious then the clone pinkies would be cloned serious.   I Rest My Case

Answer (score -1):

Well, let us take a looksy.
Pinkie, whom was having an issue being in the right place at the right time, was focused on being there for all of her friends at once. And as we were told, she wanted to go to the Mirror Pool in search of a way to DO this. You're basically asking what was cloned of Pinkie, correct? Seeing as her main derogative was to have fun with all of her gal pals, her main priority was to have fun. Though, another was to be there for each. I partially agree with Sopoforic on their theory of the pool only transmitting what was desired into the replica. Though, 'fun' was not her only directive. She wanted, as i've said plenty before, to be there for each of her friends so none of them felt left out. So her focus points were 'Fun' and 'Presence'. I also disagree on Sopoforic's reasoning of the memories of friends still being within the clones. Well, don't you remember that the real Pinkie needed to remind each clone of who was who? And where they were? If they had memory of Pinkie's friends they wouldn't have needed that kind of refresher on who they were. 
My theory is somewhat related to both Kaylie's and Sopomorphic's, but slightly altered.
Rather than have the clones remember pals and have one focus, they actually are only influenced through APPEARANCE and EMOTION.
We see that, obviously, all Pinkie clones look the same, yes? Each share the same cutie mark, 4th wall breaking habits, cute hair and eyes and bubbly personalities. 
And we can see that when the first clone of Pinkie Pie is distressed and crying, the original Pinkie does whatshe can to console herself. So we know that the clones can experience the same emotion.
Memory is not a factor when it comes to this blend, but Magic does do it's toll in the end. 
Whatever the case, we still all love our adorable 4th wall cutie, Pinkie Pie.
But i can't help but raise a bit of suspicion.
Remember when Pinkie Pie was trying to remember the rhyme that activated the enchantments of the pool? Well she did say that her GrandMother had taught her it. 
When exactly had Pinkie's Grandma DONE it? How did she find out? What happened after she herself entered? 
I know these questions are something to beconsidered by a different forum, but if any of you have speculations on the topic, i'd love to hear :)

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that they were effectively horcruxes. Each copy split off a portion of Pinkie's soul to power it, placed in a magically constructed body. Think a Naruto shadow clone or Diary Tom Riddle.

I agree with the idea that as far as mind and memories went, they got only what Pinkie was concentrating on at the time, having fun with her friends. They were a *reflection* of Pinkie at that moment in time, not the full pony.

The original Pinkie changed after the mass of clones were created becoming listless and depressed, drained of willpower possibly a side effect of having so much of her soul removed. With Voldemort, it's fairly certain that having his soul split so many ways drove him insane.

This would also mean that far from destroying new lifeforms by returning the clones to the mirror pool, Twilight saved Pinkie's sanity by releasing the soul fragments to return to her. It also means that if the real Pinkie had been hit by the spell it would have no effect.

Though there is the possible Pinkie from Saddle Row Review. In the Xanth books it suggested that a partial soul would regrow  over time. Maybe they missed one and that's what happened. If that clone was returned, it might be effectively killed, depending on whether it's memeories would be returned to the original Pinkie, as in Naruto.